# Amazon Redshift - Pivot Large JSON Arrays

Tags: sql, json, pivot, amazon-redshift, explode

I have an optimisation problem.

I have a table containing about 15MB of JSON stored as rows of `VARCHAR(65535)`.  Each JSON string is an array of arbitrary size.

- 95% contains 16 or fewer elements
- the longest (to date) contains 67 elements
- the hard limit is 512 elements (before 64kB isn't big enough)

The task is simple, pivot each array such that each element has its own row.

```
 id | json
----+---------------------------------------------
 01 | [{"something":"here"}, {"fu":"bar"}]

=>

 id | element_id | json
----+------------+---------------------------------
 01 |     1      | {"something":"here"}
 01 |     2      | {"fu":"bar"}
```

Without having any kind of table valued functions *(user defined or otherwise)*, I've resorted to pivoting via joining against a numbers table.

```
SELECT
    src.id,
    pvt.element_id,
    json_extract_array_element_text(
        src.json,
        pvt.element_id
    )
        AS json
FROM
    source_table         AS src
INNER JOIN
    numbers_table        AS pvt(element_id)
       ON pvt.element_id < json_array_length(src.json)
```

The numbers table has 512 rows in it (0..511), and the results are correct.

The elapsed time is horrendous.  And it's not to do with distribution or sort order or encoding.  It's to do with *(I believe)* redshift's materialisation.

The working memory needed to process 15MB of JSON text is 7.5GB.

- 15MB * 512 rows in `numbers` = 7.5GB

If I put just 128 rows in `numbers` then the working memory needed reduces by 4x and the elapsed time similarly reduces *(not 4x, the real query does other work, it's still writing the same amount of results data, etc, etc)*.

So, I wonder, what about adding this?

```
WHERE
    pvt.element_id < (SELECT MAX(json_array_length(src.json)) FROM source_table)
```

No change to the working memory needed, the elapsed time goes up slightly *(effectively a WHERE clause that has a cost but no benefit)*.

I've tried making a CTE to create the list of 512 numbers, that didn't help.  I've tried making a CTE to create the list of numbers, with a WHERE clause to limit the size, that didn't help *(effectively Redshift appears to have materialised using the 512 rows and THEN applied the WHERE clause)*.

My current effort is to create a temporary table for the numbers, limited by the WHERE clause.  In my sample set this means that I get a table with 67 rows to join on, instead of 512 rows.

That's still not great, as that ONE row with 67 elements dominates the elapsed time *(every row, no matter how many elements, gets duplicated 67 times before the `ON pvt.element_id < json_array_length(src.json)` gets applied)*.

My next effort will be to work on it in two steps.

1. As above, but with a table of only 16 rows, and only for row with 16 or fewer elements
2. As above, with the dynamically mixed numbers table, and only for rows with more than 16 elements

***Question:*** Does anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: Does Redshift support lateral joins?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Nothing resembling LATERAL, APPLY, table-valued-function, etc.

Comment: you should perform this outside of redshift. either by export->process->import or by processing the data prior to it arriving in redshift.

Comment: @JonScott - Yes, I agree.  That is the medium term plan *(changing that has wider ranging consequences, so is not on the immediate term plan, especially as I've already "optimised" this to just-about-tolerable timescale)*.  What I'm specifically asking is whether there is a way, once the data is on Redshift, to do this more efficiently.

Answer (score 4):

Please consider declaring the JSON as an external table. You can then use Redshift Spectrum's nested data syntax to access these values *as if* they were rows.

There is a quick tutorial here: ["Tutorial: Querying Nested Data with Amazon Redshift Spectrum"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-query-nested-data.html)

Simple example:

```
{ "id": 1
 ,"name":   { "given":"John", "family":"Smith" }
 ,"orders": [ {"price": 100.50, "quantity": 9 }
             ,{"price":  99.12, "quantity": 2 } 
            ]
}
```

---

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE spectrum.nested_tutorial
     (id      int
     ,name    struct<given:varchar(20), family:varchar(20)>
     ,orders  array<struct<price:double precision, quantity:double precision>>
     ) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://my-files/temp/nested_data/nested_tutorial/'
;
```

---

```
SELECT c.id
      ,c.name.given
      ,c.name.family
      ,o.price
      ,o.quantity
FROM spectrum.nested_tutorial c
LEFT JOIN c.orders o ON true
;
```

---

```
 id | given | family | price | quantity
----+-------+--------+-------+----------
  1 | John  | Smith  | 100.5 |        9
  1 | John  | Smith  | 99.12 |        2
```

Comment: good answer - I like this approach. You may have that data sitting on s3 prior to it being loaded to redshift!

Answer (score 0):

Neither the data format, nor the task you wish to do, is ideal for Amazon Redshift.

Amazon Redshift is excellent as a data warehouse, with the ability to do queries against billions of rows. However, **storing data as JSON is sub-optimal** because Redshift cannot use all of its abilities (eg Distribution Keys, Sort Keys, Zone Maps, Parallel processing) while processing fields stored in JSON.

The efficiency of your Redshift cluster would be much higher if the data were stored as:

```
 id | element_id | key        | value
----+------------+---------------------
 01 |     1      | something  | here
 01 |     2      | fu         | bar
```

As to how to best convert the existing JSON data into separate rows, I would frankly recommend that this is done **outside of Redshift**, then loaded into tables via the `COPY` command. A small Python script would be more efficient at converting the data that trying strange JOINs on a `numbers` table in Redshift.

Comment: This is essentially part of an ETL process to feed the warehouse.  The end result of which is that JSON doesn't exist anywhere.  That side of things is fine.  The proportions of the ingestion's elapsed time are currently 85% JSON pivoting, and 15% other ETL.  So I'm attacking the 85%.

Comment: It would be advisable to convert the JSON into normal fields as part of the ETL process prior to loading it into Redshift.

Comment: In the medium term this Will be done outside of Redshift, but in the short term that's not an option *(the external processing is agnostic to the data being delivered by an event stream from IoT devices.  Sometimes the VARCHAR(65535) has an integer, sometimes it has a JSON string.  It's a ####ing mess, and will be completely replaced as my next project, but for now it is what it is)*  That's why I'm specifically asking the question about optimising the SQL, as "today" that's the only option available.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you avoid parsing and interpreting JSON as JSON and instead work with this as text it can work faster. If you're sure about the structure of your JSON values (which I guess you are since the original query does not produce the JSON parsing error) you might try just to use `split_part` function instead of `json_extract_array_element_text`.

If your elements don't contain commas you can use:

```
split_part(src.json,',',pvt.element_id)
```

if your elements contain commas you might use

```
split_part(src.json,'},{',pvt.element_id)
```

Also, the part with `ON pvt.element_id < json_array_length(src.json)` in the join condition is still there, so to avoid JSON parsing completely you might try to cross join and then filter out non-null values.

Comment: All approaches yield the same amount of working memory. The issue is the join against a numbers table to yield a varying number of output rows. It's not the scalar operations.

Comment: you can generate the SQL code using Python, like if you hardcoded all the numbers and just copy/paste that ugly query

Comment: Do you mean `{QueryWhereElements<=1} UNION ALL {QueryWhereElements<=2} UNION ALL {etc, etc}`?  That's actually worse than what we have already.

Comment: yes, `json_extract_array_element_text(src.json, X)` where X is generated/hardcoded, and no join required. how much worse?

Comment: I have gone through your comments more thoroughly, and your consideration about materialization makes sense. can you try to add a column to your table and populate it with the result of `json_array_length(src.json)`? then you could use that column in the join condition and maybe avoid redundant materialization on the runtime